# Intentando leer una columna con pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Mi problema es muy sencillo. Tengo un csv **"sample.csv"** con 3 columnas: **[edad,altura,puntos]**

Lo unico que quiero es imprimir la primera columna "edad" del csv. Para ello utilizo este código, pero me da error.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
columna_edad = df['edad']
print(columna_edad)
```

Cuando veo tutoriales y manuales, lo hacen así y sin embargo a ellos no les da error. ¿Que es lo que hago mal?

El CSV se encuentra en el enlace: https://github.com/rbn13/csvs/blob/main/sample.csv

El error que me da es el siguiente:

```
/Users/PycharmProjects/stats1/venv/bin/python /Users/PycharmProjects/stats1/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/stats1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3361, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 76, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'edad'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/stats1/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    col = df['edad']
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/stats1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3458, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/stats1/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3363, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'edad'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Esto me condiciona a la hora de realizar los siguientes tipos de analisis estadísticos. Por ejemplo calcular la media con numpy, o la variancia, desviación estandar, anova, regresiones, etc. Por eso agradeceria que alguien me comentara como leer solo la columna seleccionada.

Comment: ¿Pero que es lo que ocurre?¿Tienes un error?¿Cual?¿Tienes un resultado distinto al que esperas?

Comment: No tenemos el csv para reproducir el error y no nos dices que error da. Sería posible para nosotros responder tu pregunta sin saber el error? "Me da error" no es suficiente. No somos adivinos.

Comment: No, en teoria lo que esperaria es que al poner la función print() de la columna "edad" me aparecieran todos los valores de esa columna. Igual que cuando poner print(df) me mostraria la tabla o dataframe entera, solo que solo querría la columna "edad". En general lo que me interesa es poder seleccionar solo una columna, porque cuando quiero calcular otras cosas con numpy tambien encuentro el mismo error. Por eso ahora mismo solo me interesa la función print(), si consigo saber porque no consigo mostrar esa columna unicamente, podré aplicarlo a otras funciones mas complejas después.

Comment: Indica el separador al leer el archivo. `pd.read_csv('sample.csv', sep=";")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Intenta esto:**

1. Con `header=0` indicamos que no tome en cuenta la cabecera del archivo, o sea las columnas.
2. Con `sep=";"` indicamos el separador de datos entre columnas.

**Nota:** Por lo general en los tutoriales que suelen hacer, siempre trabajan con una coma (",") como separador de datos, ya que pandas entiende que por defecto se usa una coma (","), entonces al buscar la columna edad te da error porque pandas espera un csv separado por comas, y en este caso deberías especificar el separador de datos que usas para poder indicarle a pandas que es lo que usaras.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', header=0, sep=";")
columna_edad = df["edad"]
print(columna_edad)
```

Comment: Buen día, gracias por el aporte. Podrías mejorar un poco tu respuesta al incluir detalles del por qué utilizar `header` y `sep`. Las diferencia entre las buenas respuestas y las excelentes está en los detalles. Recuerda que no es solamente dar la solución sino también intentar explicar el por qué. Saludos!

Comment: Genial, ahora lo entiendo todo. Ya he probado de especificar el seprador, y ahora todo funciona a la perfección. Ahora los analisis estadísticos me salen con los otros csv tambien. No me había dado cuenta del detalle de las comas. Muchísimas gracias a todos, porque este simple error me estaba dando muchos quebraderos de cabeza!!